# Having trouble with GET method Clockify API

Tags: clockify

I am currently trying to use Clockify's API and when I input the following line in my terminal:

```
curl -H 'content-type':'application/json' -H 'X-Api-Key':'UserKey' -X GET https://api.clockify.me/api/workspaces/workspaceid/projects
```

I get the following message:

> {"timestamp":"2019-01-08T17:24:47.011+0000","status":404,"error":"Not
>   Found","message":"No message
>   available","path":"/workspaces/workspaceid/projects"}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you're missing the forward dash at the end of the command. Just add / at the end of the URL and everything should work fine.

https://api.clockify.me/api/workspaces/workspaceid/projects/